# Is it possible to access 3rd party APIs from the client/browser?

Tags: javascript, api, server, client

I am implementing a weather API using lat/long from the client.  It would be easier to send the request from the browser.

Otherwise I have to send the lat/long to the server and then make the API request.

I'm not sure if it depends upon the API, but here is one option that is implemented on the server:

[weatherapi](https://rapidapi.com/weatherapi/api/weatherapi-com/)

```
const axios = require("axios");

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com/current.json',
  params: {q: '<REQUIRED>'}
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: 1) The client sent with xhr the data to the server,  2)The server make a GET request to the https://weatherapi-com.p.rapidapi.com using the API KEY 3) Get the answer/data 4) response to the client the anwer/data.  Αll because of  API KEY

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the APIs CORS settings. Most APIs only allow whitelisted URLs and block requests from other urls. (Browser)

This cannot be bypassed, except, you build an own API, which then makes the request on the backend.